# tonumber returs nil and i can't find a solution

Tags: lua, scripting, lua-table, roblox

So I was doing an advanced calculator in Roblox and I got stuck in the equal button I've already tried everything I can even restarting the entire code but everything I try when I press the equal button (let's suppose that I typed 1+1) or it returns nil, 1+1 or just an error but it never returns what I want 2.
Here is the code:

````
-- Geral Variables
local Screen = game.workspace.Cauculator.Screen
local Potency2 = game.workspace.Cauculator.Potency2
local Potency3 = game.workspace.Cauculator.Potency3
local Potency4 = game.workspace.Cauculator.Potency4
local Minus = game.workspace.Cauculator.Minus
local Plus = game.workspace.Cauculator.Plus
local Percent = game.Workspace.Cauculator.Percent
local Times = game.Workspace.Cauculator.Mutiply
local SquareRoot = game.Workspace.Cauculator.SquareRoot
local Divide = game.Workspace.Cauculator.Divide
local Equal = game.Workspace.Cauculator.Equal
local Number = {}
local Result = nil
-- functions
function Press1 ()
    table.insert(Number, "1")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)
        
        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')
        
    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["1"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press1)

function Press2 ()
    table.insert(Number, "2")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["2"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press2)

function Press3 ()
    table.insert(Number, "3")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["3"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press3)

function Press4 ()
    table.insert(Number, "4")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["4"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press4)

function Press5 ()
    table.insert(Number, "5")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["5"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press5)

function Press6 ()
    table.insert(Number, "6")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["6"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press6)

function Press7 ()
    table.insert(Number, "7")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["7"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press7)

function Press8 ()
    table.insert(Number, "8")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["8"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press8)

function Press9 ()
    table.insert(Number, "9")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["9"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press9)

function Press0 ()
    table.insert(Number, "0")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
game.Workspace.Cauculator["0"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Press0)

function PressPlus ()
    table.insert(Number, "+")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
Plus.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(PressPlus)

function PressMinus ()
    table.insert(Number, "-")
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Screen.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', '')

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
end
Minus.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(PressMinus)

function PressEqual ()
    
    game:GetService("LogService").MessageOut:Connect(function (M, T)

        Result = tonumber(string.gsub(tostring(M), '%s+', ''))
        print(Result)

    end)
    print(unpack(Number))
    
end
Equal.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(PressEqual)```
````

Answer (score 1):

`tonumber` doesn't evaluate expressions, it's purpose to parse a number from string.

To make a working calculator, you need to make a parser that detects numbers and math operators and then does the logic of evaluation.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoVeras If I answered you, please mark the question as "answered", this is how you do on StackOverflow. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)